# Current date/time in TDateTime variable

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I am using C++ and am using the TDateTime data type.

How can I get the current system date/time and place it into a TDateTime variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `Now()`, `TDateTime t = Now();`. [Here is a tutorial](http://www.functionx.com/cppbuilder/topics/datetime.htm). You should be able to figure this stuff out by a simple search. Please try to make more effort in trying to figure out these problems by yourself.

Answer (score 5):

As Jesse mentioned, you can use the `Now()` function (or the static `TDateTime::CurrentDateTime()` method).  Do note that on Windows, internally it calls the Win32 API `GetLocalTime()` function, which returns the system date/time in the local timezone.  If you want the current system date/time in UTC instead, you can write your own function that calls `GetSystemTime()` instead of `GetLocalTime()`:

```
TDateTime __fastcall NowUTC()
{
  SYSTEMTIME SystemTime;
  ::GetSystemTime(&SystemTime);
  return EncodeDate(SystemTime.wYear, SystemTime.wMonth, SystemTime.wDay) + EncodeTime(SystemTime.wHour, SystemTime.wMinute, SystemTime.wSecond, SystemTime.wMilliseconds);
}
```